# <error: unknown Class> for NSString instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am declaring an instance of `NSString` named *strKey and `@synthesize` and i pass one string value to it.

But when I want to send that string to another class. it is giving me error of

[image]

Here is my code

Assigning one value to the strKey here

```
 -(IBAction)getLocal:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [self startDeckDownload];
        GroupDeckExpandableViewObject *objConfiguration=[[GroupDeckExpandableViewObject alloc] init];
        GroupListCell *celltest=(GroupListCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview;

        if(celltest != nil){
            celltest.viewDownload.hidden =NO;
            celltest.viewGetLocal.hidden=YES;
            //objConfiguration.vwWelcome=celltest.viewWelcome;
            objConfiguration.vwGetLocal=celltest.viewGetLocal;
            objConfiguration.vwDownLoad=celltest.viewDownload;
            strKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]]; // i am assign one value to the string here.
            [delegate setGroupViewConfiguration:objConfiguration withtag:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]]];

        }

    }
```

passing to another class(using protocol).

```
-(void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress
{

    [delegate setDownloadProgress:progress withkey:strKey];
}
```

Here is the definition to the protocol method.

```
@protocol groupListCellDelegate<NSObject>

@optional
- (void) setGroupViewConfiguration:(id)objConfiguration withtag:(NSString *)key;
-(void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress withkey:(NSString *)key;
@end
```

I use this method in my `GroupView.m`

```
#pragma mark - delegate method

    -(void)setGroupViewConfiguration:(id)objConfiguration withtag:(NSString *)key
    {

        [arrGroupViewConfiguration setValue:objConfiguration forKey:key];
        GroupDeckExpandableViewObject *objgetviews=[arrGroupViewConfiguration valueForKey:key];
         [tblData reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objgetviews.cellIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
     //   [tblData reloadData];
    }

    -(void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress withkey:(NSString *)key
    {
        NSLog(@"Reloaded...");
        progress_percent = progress;
        GroupDeckExpandableViewObject *objgetviews=[arrGroupViewConfiguration valueForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%d",objgetviews.cellIndexPath.section);
        [tblData reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objgetviews.cellIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      //  [tblData reloadData];
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post your code..that will help you understand and figure out your mistake..

Comment: ok i am posting my code

Comment: How is the delegate method `setDonwloadProgress:withKey:` defined?

Comment: And at what line of execution are you seeing the strange value in the debugger?

Comment: Please post your full portion delegation code...I think you have issue over there

Comment: when this method is call the error is coming.

Comment: When which method is called? You posted two.

Comment: first it is call -(IBAction)getLocal:(UIButton *)sender then -(void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress is  called

Comment: Is ARC enabled for this file or no?

Comment: @BaZinga And then `setDownloadProgress:withKey:` is called. Where along this execution path do you see the strange value for `strKey`? And you still haven't shown us how `setDownloadProgress:withKey:` is defined.

Comment: i add the definition of method now

Comment: ok you mean to say that value is not retaining right @rmaddy

Comment: @BaZinga I've said nothing about the value being retained or not. I'm still trying to find out from you where along the execution path of your code that you are stopping to view `strKey` and seeing the strange value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You own the object returned from `initWithFormat` which you are responsible for releasing, but you don't own the object returned from `stringWithFormat` which returns an autoreleased string and so do not need to release it (if you do want to have ownership of it, you must retain it).

So for resolving your issue try to assign your value like this,

```
strKey=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]];
```

Comment: @baZinga  It's my pleasure.